# Adding two List<String> in one List<String>

Tags: java

I have two Lists

```
List<String> list1 =new ArrayList<String>() ;
List<String> list2 =new ArrayList<String>() ;
```

I want these two lists to append one after other and send to a set method for my bean. Please let me know what is the best way to combine these two lists.

Comment: `list1.addAll(list2)`; or `List<String> joined = new ArrayList<>(list1); joined.addAll(list2);` if you want to keep `list1` unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
list1.addAll(list2)
```

That will add all elements from list2 at end of list1

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
List<String> appended = new ArrayList<>(lis1); // copy of list1
appended.addAll(list2);                      // add all elements of list2
```

`appended` is a new `List` containing all elements from `list1` and `list2`. No list got hurt during the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .addAll() to add the elements of the second list to the first:

```
array1.addAll(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To combine the lists, you can just do `addAll` like so:

```
list1.addAll(list2) //Adds list1 to list2
```

[Link to the addAll documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29)